# Bingo Card with non repeating randomized numbers (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

So far i've managed to randomize the numbers in the range I want and assign them to all buttons, but i can't figure out how to not repeat them, since the goal is to make a bingo card. All help is appreciated, code so far looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Random randomizador = new Random();
        Button btns[]= new Button[25];
        btns[0] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btns[1] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btns[2] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btns[3] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btns[4] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btns[5] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btns[6] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btns[7] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btns[8] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btns[9] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn10);
        btns[10] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn11);
        btns[11] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn12);
        btns[12] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn13);
        btns[13] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn14);
        btns[14] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn15);
        btns[15] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn16);
        btns[16] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn17);
        btns[17] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn18);
        btns[18] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn19);
        btns[19] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn20);
        btns[20] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn21);
        btns[21] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn22);
        btns[22] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn23);
        btns[23] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn24);
        btns[24] = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn25);

        for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
            int num = randomizador.nextInt(100);
            btns[i].setText(String.valueOf(num));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an array of already chosen numbers and if it is repeated simply generate new random number.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, maybe with a piece of code, thanks for the help

Comment: Create arraylist of Integer(ArrayList<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<>(); ) also the function provided below and write `btns[i].setText(getUniqueNumber());`
 
`public String getUniqueNumber(){
        int num = randomizador.nextInt(100);
        for (Integer integer : generated) {
            if (integer == num){
                getUniqueNumber();
            }
        }
        generated.add(num);
        return (String.valueOf(num));
    }`

Comment: replace `for (Integer integer : generated) { if (integer == num){ getUniqueNumber(); } `

with `for (int i = 0; i < generated.size(); i++) {
            if (generated.get(i) == num) {
                getUniqueNumber();
            }
        }` or it will throw an exception.